# How to set active class to web web-font icon generated from icomoon

Tags: html, css

I created a set of icons from icomoon, I can set the hover style just like this

```
.icon-github:hover::before {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

but I am trying to set it to a specific color when it is an active class like this

```
.icon-home:before .active {
  color: #08FDD8 !important;
}
```

all to no avail, this is how it looks like on HTML

```
<li><a><span class="icon-twitter active"></span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your css is looking for the `.active` class to be a *child* of `.icon-home`. setting aside the `:before` psuedo selector the following CSS:

```css
.icon-home .active {
  color: #08FDD8 !important;
}
```

would target the following markup:

```html
<li><a><span class="icon-twitter">
    <span class="active"></span>
</span></a></li>
```

because the `.active` class is modifying the `.icon-home` class you want to chain your selectors together like so:

```css
.active.icon-home::before {
  color: #08FDD8 !important;
}

/* or */

.icon-home.active::before {
  color: #08FDD8 !important;
}
```